# Question regarding a graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a finitely generated graded ring over $A$. So degree $0$ elements of $S$ is $A$ and
we assume that there is no negative degree elements here. 
Thus, we have that $S$ is generated over $A$ by a finite number of homogeneous elements 
of positive degree, say $\{ t_1, ..., t_m \}$. Does it then follow that
$(S_{t_i})_0$, which is the degree $0$ elements of the ring $S_{t_i}$, is also finitely generated over $A$? Thanks!

By $S_{t_i}$ I mean the localization of $S$ at $t_i$.